# Do I lose all my question-votes if I go back and edit my question?

Tags: support, questions, voting

Just got a question solved, and I selected an answer. For the sake of clarity I would like to go back to my original question and put the solution in the answer.

Since my Question has multiple votes and it's favorited, will I lose those votes and favorite if I go back and edit the original question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Votes are saved for the question in general, no matter of the revision.

In case a revision is really bad, people have the possibility to change their votes each time the question is edited. There is nothing automatic though, votes will stay.